# Convert byte array to bit in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, byte, bit

I have this array:

```
byte addr[5] = {0x56,0x5A, 0x11, 0x40, 0xBE};
```

How do I convert it to `0x565A1140BE` in Arduino?

Comment: Use the bitwise `<<` and `|` operators.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just construct the value from the bytes

```
byte addr[5] = {0x56,0x5A, 0x11, 0x40, 0xBE};
uint64_t value = ((uint64_t)addr[0] << 32)
               | ((uint64_t)addr[1] << 24)
               | ((uint64_t)addr[2] << 16)
               | ((uint64_t)addr[3] << 8)
               | ((uint64_t)addr[4] << 0);
```

You can also treat the bytes as an `uint64_t` value directly. This may be much faster but it depends on the endianness, although Arduino compilers typically use little endian

```
uint64_t value = 0;
byte addr[5] = {0x56,0x5A, 0x11, 0x40, 0xBE};
// Copy the 5 bytes to the low bytes of the big endian value
memcpy((char*)&value + 3, addr, 5);
// The high 3 bytes will remain zero because we already initialized `value` to 0

#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
value = __builtin_bswap64(value); // reverse endian
#endif
```

If the array is 8 bytes long then just copy the whole 8 bytes, no need to initialize to 0 first

```
memcpy((char*)&value, addr, 8);
```

Comment: Hmm, good answer.. but if the array is, for example, eight bytes long, what to do then? how then to do with the first decision

Comment: @3peekawOwD obviously with 8 bytes then just copy the whole 8 bytes into `uint64_t`. In fact if aliasing is allowed then you can do this directly `uint64_t value = *(uint64_t*)&addr`

Comment: It return 0x5A00000056

Comment: @3peekawOwD then you're doing it wrong. Without code no one can tell you why

Comment: `byte addr[8] = {0x56,0x5A, 0x11, 0x40, 0xBE, 0x56, 0x5A, 0x11}; uint64_t value = *(uint64_t*)&addr;` It return 5A00000056

Comment: @3peekawOwD then it's because of aliasing which invokes undefined behavior. As I said, you can only do that when aliasing is allowed. You still need to do memcpy

Comment: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Comment: @3peekawOwD again there's no code to see. And don't ask questions in comments like that

Comment: Your memcpy code returned this error, I replaced the array and changed 5 to 8 in memcpy

Comment: @3peekawOwD there's no error: https://godbolt.org/z/qTqPY4Mr7 the only thing here is `byte` which isn't a standard type. Sometimes you'll want `&addr` instead of `addr` but it's irrelevant in this case. And of course you also need to change the offset from 3 to 0 if you copy 8 bytes instead of 5